# @Published property in @EnvironmentObject doesn't update the root view of my application

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, environmentobject

I am trying to make a router object for my application using @EnvironmentObject. But the problem is the @Published property doesn't update the root view when the root view type is updated.

#### How it should work

1. A user clicks **Sign in with Apple** button
2. Update the router.currentPage property of @EnvironmentObject when a user logs in successfully.
3. RootView get notified for updating router.currentPage and change the root view in accordance to the updated currentPage type.

Here are my codes below.

**MainApp.swift**

```
var body: some Scene {
  WindowGroup {              
    RootView().environmentObject(ViewRouter())
  }
}
```

**ViewRouter.swift**

```
Code Block 
enum Page {
 case signin
 case tasklist
}
final class ViewRouter: ObservableObject { 
    @Published var currentPage: Page = .signin
 }
```

**RootView.swift**

```
struct RootView: View {
 @EnvironmentObject var router: ViewRouter
 var body: some View {
  if router.currentPage == .signin {
   SigninView()
  } else {
   TaskListView()
  }
 }
}
```

**SigninView.swift**

```
struct SigninView: View {
 @EnvironmentObject var router: ViewRouter
 @State var signInHandler: SignInWithAppleCoordinator?
  
 var window: UIWindow? {
  guard let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first,
     let windowSceneDelegate = scene.delegate as? UIWindowSceneDelegate,
     let window = windowSceneDelegate.window else {
   return nil
  }
  return window
 }
  
 var body: some View {
  MyAppleIDButton().colorScheme(.light)
   .frame(width: 280, height: 38, alignment: .center)
   .onTapGesture {
    signInWithAppleButtonTapped()
   }
 }
  
 func signInWithAppleButtonTapped() {
  guard let _window = self.window else { return }
  signInHandler = SignInWithAppleCoordinator(window: _window)
  signInHandler?.signIn { (user) in
   router.currentPage = .tasklist
  }
 }
}
```

## Update

I think I found an answer to this issue.
I created a state `isLoggedIn` which is checking whether or not `Sign in with Apple` is done successfully.

```
@State var isLoggedIn: Bool = false
```

Then I added **View Modifier** `onChange` which is checking the value change of isLoggedIn above. Inside the `onChange` I assigned a new value to `router.currentPage` like below.

```
.onChange(of: isLoggedIn, perform: { isLoggedIn in
  if isLoggedIn {
    router.currentPage = .tasklist
      } else {
        router.currentPage = .signin
      }
  })
```

But I am still not sure of why it doesn't work in the closure of SigninWithApple button.

Comment: Did you debug if you get into `router.currentPage = .tasklist` line?

Comment: @Asperi Yes, I added breakpoints to the lines and it successfully updated `router.currentPage` property.